# AlertDialog - Trying to get the Alert to work

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog

So I have searched through a few question here regarding the AlertDialog, and I'm not completely sure what I'm doing, so I am having a hard time relating those questions to my own example.  (I'm still new to this whole android programming so please bear with me.)

I have defined this under the public class *_* Activity implements OnCLickListener ...

```
    public AlertDialog myAlertDialog;
```

And then I have this under the onClick

```
    public void onClick(View src) {

    switch(src.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonOk:
        if (score==0){
            AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            myAlertDialog.setTitle("Title");
            myAlertDialog.setMessage("Message");
            myAlertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                } }); 
            myAlertDialog.show();
        }
```

This line and the line below it have errors:

```
myAlertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

Errors:

1st: Multiple markers at this line
    - DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method setButton(String, new OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type

2nd: DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just aren't importing the DialogInterface. Try adding this statement to the beginning of your code.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

Comment: or push ctrl+shift+O ("oh" not zero)

Comment: Sweet that worked, I will accept answer as soon as I can but could you help me with one more thing.

It now says The method setButton(String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder
on the second line.

Comment: Scratch that, just change it to setPotitiveButton and it worked!!

Thanks again so much guys... LOVE this community!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `setPositiveButton()` or `setNegativeButton()` there is no method `setButton()` on `AlertDialog.Builder`.

And make sure to import `DialogInterface`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html, the setbutton() method is defined

Comment: @John it is defined on Builder not on AlertDialog http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: Trueche.  Edit your answer to explain this so I can retract a downvote.  It threw me off the the builder and the alertdialog were named the same thing...